# Android - extracting cookies after login in webview

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview, cookiestore

I have an application that opens a url in a webview, the user must then login to a site through the webview and receives a cookie once logged in. I'm having problems getting cookies after login.

The problem is, I can achieve this using android.webkit.CookieManager, and output all cookies in a single string.

However, I want to achieve it using the a cookie store (as in java.net.CookieStore) so I need to be using java.net.CookieManager.

I'm using the following code within the onPageFinished() of a WebViewClient. I know the issue is with opening a new connection, where I need to be getting the content from the current page. I'd appreciate some help, thanks

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

            Log.d(TAG, "Finished loading: " + url);

            CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Main.this);
            syncManager.sync();

            CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
            manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

            try {
                URL blah = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) blah.openConnection();
                readStream(con.getInputStream()); // outputting html
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            }

            CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
            List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();

            for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
                Log.d(TAG, "cookie name : "+cookie.getName().toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Already answered but for completeness and might help someone, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15924948/1714030

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can extract all cookies current url by this way from webview as string:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
}
```

Comment: mrboyfox, do you have any idea about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256509/how-do-i-resolve-the-authentication-message-that-keeps-popping-up-in-a-webview/19256608?noredirect=1#comment28533391_19256608

Comment: doesn't work when the page has a redirect through JS. onPageFinished is not called for every page.

Comment: @ItayBianco You can add another answer to your a situation if you have a solution too. It is will be great to developers which is looking solution to this a situation.

Comment: Does not work if cookie has SameSite flag. CookieManager just does not return that kind of cookie

Comment: import android.webkit.CookieManager;

Answer (score 40):

It was a quite late , but it might help someone

you can get the cookie value using this

```
getCookie("http://www.example.com","cookieName");
```

Declare the function as

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String cookieName){     
    String CookieValue = null;

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);       
    String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
    for (String ar1 : temp ){
        if(ar1.contains(cookieName)){
            String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
            CookieValue = temp1[1];
            break;
        }
    }              
    return CookieValue; 
}
```

Comment: why do you need the [] in those regexes which are used for splitting strings?

Comment: @RaduSimionescu they don't seem necessary to me, but they won't hurt, either

Comment: @gengkev in that case, why not type in something like "(([;])){1}{1,1}"  ?

Comment: @RaduSimionescu :) well, i suppose the author might have taken the regex from another piece of code and modified it?

Comment: Sorry guys i removed it , Thanks for your comments

Comment: Be aware that using `contains` will find false entries, when a cookie value contains the name to look for: `FOO=BAR; BAR=FOO`

Comment: This will break if your cookie value contains the = character

Comment: @davehenry To avoid that, add a second argument to split method, like this: String[] temp1=ar1.split("=",2);

Comment: As @althaus says, "if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){" this is dangerous, it may be better "if(ar1.indexOf(CookieName) == 0){" then you make sure you are looking for the name of the cookie and not some intermediate string that may cause a false positive.

Comment: Thanks @AlpAltunel

Answer (score 7):

This answer is derived from @vimal1083. It returns the values in a `Map`, and of course written in `Kotlin`.

```
fun getCookieMap(siteName: String): Map<String,String> {

    val manager = CookieManager.getInstance()
    val map = mutableMapOf<String,String>()

    manager.getCookie(siteName)?.let {cookies ->
        val typedArray = cookies.split(";".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        for (element in typedArray) {
            val split = element.split("=".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()

            if(split.size >= 2) {
                map[split[0]] = split[1]
            } else if(split.size == 1) {
                map[split[0]] = ""
            }
        }
    }

    return map
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this link - 
[Pass cookies from HttpURLConnection (java.net.CookieManager) to WebView (android.webkit.CookieManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731211/pass-cookies-from-httpurlconnection-java-net-cookiemanager-to-webview-android)

If you want to get cookies from webview, you will have to use `android.webkit.CookieManager`, from any `HttpUrlConnection`, however, you can extract cookies useing `java.net.CookieStore`

You will need to parse the string where you are getting all the cookies.

Comment: import android.webkit.CookieManager;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get a specific `cookie`

```
fun getCookie(name: String): String? {
    val cookies = cookieManager.getCookie("YOUR_URL_HERE")
    if (cookies == null || !cookies.contains("${name}=")) {
        return null
    }
    return cookies.split("${name}=")[1].split(";")[0]
}
```