# How to make HTTP Request with authentication info from WebView in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to extract some info from a website which requires login to access said page. I created a webview to allow to user to log in first.

The question is, how to use the authorization info from that webview in other HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the cookies from the page and use them in later requests.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
}
```

see more here:
[Android - extracting cookies after login in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100086/android-extracting-cookies-after-login-in-webview)

Comment: And how do I use said cookies?

Comment: depends what you want to do with it. Are you trying to make http calls? or use it in another webview? or....

Comment: How in that cookies you will know if the login process was successful?

Comment: Prefereably http calls.

Comment: @Hector well if it goes to a specific url when it logs in or errors you could check that. Most pages have that. Also some pages dont give you a valid cookie until the login is successful. It all depends on the specific website.

Comment: Let's assume login is successful, how do I use the cookies in a http request then?

Comment: @DavidBanker When making an http call there will be ways to add headers. just add the header with key Cookie and the value cookies string we have just gotten

Comment: @TomerShemesh ah ok, then I should to create a cookie in the web app (ie. called "logsOK") to set if the logs in was successful, then in Android ask if this cookie exist?

Comment: i think your getting mixed up. you shouldnt be creating any cookies. The website you are going to in the webview will create a cookie. Every website is different in what the cookie is called. you can use the chrome debug menu to view all the cookies and see whats created when you login.