# Android Webview and WP current user

Tags: android, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and an android app using webview, is it possible to get the current user info from wordpress to android?

Comment: if the info is shown on the page, you can call a JS method from Android into WebView, This method will return some string (your parser user info) back into the Android Java code.

Comment: I want to detect if the user is an admin, and I dont want to show it on page. I found a solution by creating my own cookies

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by adding a custom cookie to my site and parse it using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241926/8024042). But if you guys have better solution or if this will have problem in the future, tell me :)