# How to get session user id from webview

Tags: android, cookies, webview

Am trying get user session userid from android webview, but using the below code my app will forcefully stop working, without any error while building the apk. Please i am still trying to complete my first webview app am still very new in android

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String CookieName){
    String CookieValue = null;

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);
    String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
    for (String ar1 : temp ){
        if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
            String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
            CookieValue = temp1[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return CookieValue;
}
```

Reference to above code https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241926/8778864

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
 showAlert(FoodShopMainActivity.this, "Cookies", "cookies string:" + cookies);
}
```

The above code will output `PHPSESSID=g675654hghghf7ghgyty`, but what is only the session userID.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 /*String userCookie = getCookie("http://www.example.com","online_users");
  showAlert(FoodShopMainActivity.this, "Cookies", "cookies string:" + userCookie);*/
}
```

The above code will `show app has stopped working` once lunched

Comment: `forcefully stop working` means crashing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)